# Can solar energy be used to desalinate seawater in Australia?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, water, worldbuilding-resources, sea, water-bodies

An [Australian company](https://suncable.sg/) is going to send solar energy [1](https://renewablesnow.com/news/planning-deal-signed-for-massive-australia-singapore-solar-power-link-729489/), [2](https://www.ecowatch.com/worlds-largest-solar-farm-singapore-australia-2648425842.html) to [Singapore](https://www.straitstimes.com/business/economy/australia-fast-tracks-plan-to-send-solar-power-to-singapore) and likely to Indonesia.

Could or shall [Lake Eyre basin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Eyre) be flooded with desalinated seawater using the solar energy harvested at site in Central Australia?

Why this question is not posted on other SE site? Because [Greening the Sahara was asked](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/112142/greening-the-sahara/200807#200807).

@Willk For the link you post, can we use the energy from the gravity drop to desalinate? For example, [let the Pacific seawater go downwards into reversed osmosis membranes.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/getting-large-amounts-of-water-to-the-australian-outback/85840#85840)

Comment: Of course you can fill lake Erie with desalinated seawater if you really want to. But somebody needs to pay for the power, pipelines, pumps etc. *For ever*, because Lake Erie will need constant replenishment. So the question is, *why* would the 26 million Australians commit to pay 1,000 dollars per year for each man woman and baby *for ever* in order to keep Lake Erie filled with fresh water? What do they hope to get in return for this massive financial effort?

Comment: Here is a scheme to do it with no energy inputs at all.   https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/getting-large-amounts-of-water-to-the-australian-outback/85840#85840

Comment: You could turn the [Mediterranean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantropa) into a fresh water lake with enough time, money and political willpower but the question is: should you?

Comment: @AlexP: Where do you get the 26 billion dollars per year figure?  As for what they'd get, lakefront property and agricultural land.  You wouldn't (if sensible, anyway) simply pipe the water to Lake Eyre, you'd pump it to the divide of the basin, and let it run downhill from there, creating well-watered land.  That land has considerably more value: hereabouts a well-watered acre lot might sell for 100K dollars or more, vs a few thousand for nearby desert.

Comment: @jamesqf: Why would Mr. John Random Citizen pay throughout his life for other people to enjoy nice properties on the waterfront? As for the AUD 26 billion, it's an estimate extracted carefully from my stomach. (Lake Eyre, when filled, has a volume of about [30 billion cubic meters](https://wldb.ilec.or.jp/Lake/OCE-04). Left on its own, the lake evaporates in less than a year. Desalinated water costs, at best, about 1 dollar per cubic meter, and that's on the sea shore.)

Comment: @AlexP: Err... Why does Mr. Citizen pay for things like roads, bridges, dams, airports, &c?  Or FTM for other large water projects?  See for instance California: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_State_Water_Project  Note that he's not paying for those waterfront properties (unless he wants one),  They get sold to defray the cost of the project.  (I might agree about desalinization, but that seems to make little sense when Northern Australia has a number of largish rivers.)

Comment: Not sure about lake, I guess proposal is too raw if useful at all, buuut, producing fresh water with solar energy is one of the good uses of intermittent energy source. It can be connected to food growing in green houses(to save and recycle water), this connection may make things more attractive monetary wise. But it needs to be calculated, considering local needs, consumptions, demands, production etc, to see if things are good or not, better than selling or not. For sure that company isn't charity, so if they plan so then they see some economics politics sense in doing so.

Comment: The edit made to the question should not be there, and should be posted as a comment instead.

Comment: Sure you could fill the lakebed with desalinated water. Wereupon it will instantly **become more salty than the ocean** because the entire lake bed is a mass of salt!!

Comment: @PcMan can the lake bed be mined for the salt before filling? In imagination, a solar power factory may use seawater desalination to use up its extra quanta of energy. The desalinated water is "dumped" or filling the lake. Evaporation is going to make the lake saltier. Eventually (in decades?), the lake bed needs to be mined for salt. In other words, the desalination needs not be exhaustive to remove salts. as long as the energy budget is balanced.